# Is railgun propulsion being researched?

Tags: future-missions, advanced-propulsion, research, rail-gun

Specifically: not a "space gun" for launching payloads to space. This subject has been discussed a lot, and I know of the slew of problems and their partial solutions enough.

I mean a device mounted on a craft, using electricity for launching macroscopic pieces of metallic reaction mass at hypervelocity, in the opposite direction the craft is meant to move.

Railguns operating in atmosphere have limited applications and their own slew of problems. Some of them should vanish in void, while others might remain or get exacerbated. Nevertheless, if [EDO-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railgun#Tests) ever reached the planned 7000$\frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}}$ exit velocity, it would constitute an engine of over 700s of $\text{I}_{sp}$, and that's surely not the end of it - if we don't strive for heavy projectiles of aerodynamic shape and armor piercing properties, just focus on getting whatever shape ejected as fast as possible, this could see even further improvements.

Of course there would be problems. Pulsed propulsion stress, energy supply, heat dissipation and so on. But you have to admit 700s of $\text{I}_{sp}$ sounds very tempting.

And of course I'd be very surprised if I was the first to think of it. So - has this been attempted, developed, researched? Some unforeseen problems that make it totally impossible or otherwise a misguided endeavor?

Comment: Hm, I wonder if we could pilot an asteroid like this by launching its own mass away...

Comment: There was a scheme with mass drivers using asteroidal material as reaction mass. Google MADMEN asteroids.

Comment: I wonder how long it would be before spitting out a gigantic quantity of small fast-moving objects near Earth or installations in space would be a problem...

Comment: @kimholder: I imagined it would be, so the craft would likely be sending projectiles into the atmosphere to burn up. Or at least into escape trajectory. Besides, I imagine with the energies involved, the projectiles might be leaving the engine as vapor, or at least a very fine liquid mist.

Comment: Mass-throwers are worth evaluating for specific applications. ISP and thrust/weight are the key performance factors when launching from a gravity well and carrying all of your propellant. ISP is a function of exhaust velocity and, for a rocket, the molecular weight of your propellant. So you are giving up ISP by throwing rocks or metallic slugs, not hydrogen. However if you are moving an asteroid then your system is not mass-limited, it's energy-limited and launch-system-mass limited. The Wikipedia article on ISP links to another on energy efficiency, worth checking out.

Comment: The idea of 'mass throwing' is and old one in science fiction. Rail gun propulsion sounds good, though I think maintenance would be a big problem. They take a lot of power, though, Like a nuclear reactor. Nuclear reactors aren't allowed in space at the moment, but that will probably change eventually. There's no way one of those thermal nuclear power units would be able to power rail guns.

Comment: @HowardMiller:It's just the matter of average thrust. The battery of capacitors can trickle-charge over a long time until it reaches level when the railgun shots. Of course in that variant it's way inferior to ion engines, which could provide similar thrust over that time from the same source, and with better ISp. But it seems like a serious competitor to NTR - NTR throttling down means losing ISp with the same mass flow. Railgun reduces mass flow with no ISp loss, and potentially offers better ISp overall with decent thrust. How it compares to a *battery* of ion drives though?

Comment: I suspect ion drives would be the better way to go. A rail gun is essentially a short circuit with a very high current. Any imperfection in a rail is going to grow with each shot, until the gun has to be shut down and the rail fixed, either by repair or by replacement.
You'd have to have a hell of an ion drive to get you up to speed in any appropriate amount of time, and the total energy expended will be roughly the same. I say 'roughly' because there'd be some wasted energy one way or another.

Comment: @HowardMiller: Yes, if we find source of xenon in deep space. For crafts launched/fueled from Earth, I agree, simply toss as many ion drives as you need for desired thrust, and nothing will beat that. But if you plan a sample return mission from Ceres, you might consider something that can be fueled at Ceres.

Comment: @HowardMiller: Also, I'm not sure but I suspect it might scale better with high thrust. If you are willing to put a nuclear reactor on your craft, the railgun may cost less than three hundred ion drives, providing roughly the same thrust and similar ISp. But until we see some space-worthy prototypes, that's just a baseless hunch.

Comment: @Kengineer: Ion engines usually use Xenon rather than the lower-atomic-mass Krypton because, in this regime, thrust is a bigger concern than Isp; and higher atomic mass tends to give higher thrust in exchange for lower Isp. The proposed "rail gun engine" is extrapolating this trend to an extreme.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Made on Space is researching a similar idea.   [Plan to Turn Asteroids Into Spaceships](http://www.space.com/33079-turning-asteroids-into-spaceships-made-in-space.html)

> the propulsion system might be some sort of catapult that launches boulders or other material off the asteroid in a controlled way, thereby pushing the space rock in the opposite direction (as described by Newton's Third Law of Motion)

While the Made in Space plan involves much simpler forms of object expulsion then a rail gun to create propulsion, the basic principles still apply.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect that if you have the electric power available to fire macroscopic projectiles from a railgun, you're better off accelerating Xenon gas with it. Current ion thrusters yield exhaust velocities above 30,000m/s. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_thruster

Comment: I was wondering if this might be the case. Xenon is expensive, though.

Comment: At $850/kg it's not going to break the bank for small probes, and MPDTs can get similarly efficient performance on hydrogen.

Comment: You might want to link to another resource like [this](https://www.quora.com/With-Xenon-supplies-diminishing-on-earth-where-will-we-get-more-to-use-in-future-ion-thruster-engines/answer/Michael-Busch-4?srid=kKeL) then, because your Wiki article claims that Xenon is in short supply.

Comment: 30,000m/s at what thrust? Also, iron asteroids are a dime a dozen, while finding xenon in space is going to be challenging...

Comment: @called2voyage There's plenty of xenon in the atmosphere. It is global production that limits supply. Xenon is often discarded in the process of liquefying oxygen and nitrogen from our atmosphere. If there were a large demande for it, it wouldn't be hard to ramp up production.

Comment: You don't need xenon necessarily. Any readily ionizable gas in sufficient quantity would work, even vaporized rock.

Answer (score 2):

From a science fiction perspective, there is a book [Heart of the Comet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart_of_the_Comet) by Gregory Benford and David Brin about an attempt to corral Halleys comet into Earth orbit. At apogee, they use mass-slingers, basically railguns firing mined mass from the comet to transfer momentum and 'fly the comet'.

Great story regardless, but Brin and Benford are actual scientists, who often pay at least superficial care to the science in the story.

Comment: 'Heart Of The Comet' is a good read. I recommend it.